# cant get POM file to set the outputDirectoryas as the project root

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have a POM.xml file and when i compile it it spits out the files in a default directory within the project. Is there a way to specify the file output within the

```
<outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
```

field? I would likle the file output to be in the root of the project folder. i want the output directory to be able to work for multiple users wherever the project is located within a computer.so it must not be specific for a single user. Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by `default directory within the project`? And what file output do you mean? The compiled classes? The default is `target` folder?

Comment: The default is in target but id rather it be in the same folder as the pom file. yes, i mean the compiled classes.

Comment: The target folder is sibling to the pom.xml file yes. The compiled classes are put into `target/classes` and the test classes are put into `target/test-classes`....Apart from that why do you like to put the outputdirectory to the root folder cause that would interfere with your version control and will create many files you don't like to pollute your folders with...keep them separated into target folder.

Comment: i just want to be able to output the file to any directory within my C: drive that is all. I understand that it is "bad practice" but this is what i need to do.

Comment: The result of your build is created in the target folder. So what exactly is the problem to leave it there and if your really to have it somewhere else just copy it there. Within a Maven build this does not make sense. Why do you like to change a configuration in this bad things? What do you like to achieve? (Please don't tell me i just want to do that) ...Can you give more detailed reasons for that...